# Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for Flickr

Tags: foreach, flickr, phpflickr

I recently switched our site to a different server for ExpressionEngine and all of a sudden I'm getting errors when trying to access a drop down list of Flickr albums.

This is what the error says:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: flickr_sets/ft.flickr_sets.php
Line Number: 35

Here is the code for the php file...line 35-37

```
foreach($sets['photoset'] as $photoset) {
$photo_sets[$photoset['id']] = $photoset['title'];
}
```

I haven't changed anything but am wondering if I need to reauthorize the token since I switched to a different server.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you get this resolved as I have the same problem after a site move between servers?